# Using jQuery, how do I add elements to a jQuery object that's yet to be created?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Perhaps I am doing this wrong and suggestions on how to improve my code are appreciated. My situation is this: I have a toolbar with different elements that are populated by a callback. I do not want to use the show() or hide() commands, I prefer to use detach, but I think there should be a nice way to deal with it. Here's my code:

```
entryView = function _entryView() {

    var menuButton = $('<div/>').addClass('menuButton');        

    toolBar();

    $.getJSON('ajax', function(o) {
        var $enum2 = ss.IEnumerator.getEnumerator(dto.TransmittalDates);
        while ($enum2.moveNext()) {
            var dateTime = $enum2.get_current();
            $('.menu').append($('<div/>').addClass('menuitem').text(dateTime.toString()));
        }
    });
}
    toolBar = function _toolBar() {
    var flyoutMenu = $('<div/>').addClass('menu');

    $('.menuButton').click(function(o) {
          $('.menubutton').append(flyoutMenu);
    });
```

I did a quick cut and paste and renamed the variables to make them make sense.  As you can see on the entry I build the toolbar and the very last thing I do is the ajax call. The menu, however, is not created until the "click" event, so appending is not possible.

I realize that having global variables is bad, so I'm trying to avoid that, but I think the best situation would have the ajax call populate a Menu variable and when the DOM is created, to pull from that same Menu item. How do I pull this off? Is there a better way to do it?

Edit: Fubbed a bit on the toolbar function, I think I have it should be correct now.

Comment: Why do you prefer deatch?  I ask because this is a *lot* more expensive than show/hide. If I guessed, probably by a few thousand times more expensive at least.

Comment: I don't understand what `toolbar();` is supposed to do; in fact given that code I'm pretty sure it'll result in a run-time error.

Comment: If you're trying to delay attachment until after the attached element is created, but you need to write the attachment code before the element is created, then perhaps this is a use case for a closure?

Comment: I didn't realize detach() was so expensive, what's the advantage of show/hide then?

Comment: @Geoffrey - `show()`/`hide()` is just toggling a CSS property, `.detach()` is moving DOM elements around, which is much more expensive that pretty much anything you can do.  It's a matter of "how much work does this do?"....and `.detach()` does *much* more work in the browser.

Comment: Here's an [article](http://insideria.com/2008/11/visible-false-versus-removechi.html) comparing the approaches - `removeChild()` used by `detach()`, `visible` that is somewhat similar to setting the `display` property used by `show()/hide()` vs `alpha` transparency (worst of the bunch). That said, your question still doesn't make any sense. Where does detach come into all of this? The code itself gives very little hints - `$('.menu').append(flyoutMenu);` appending an element to itself is not very helpful.

Comment: Oops, I think I have it right now. I've tried the show/hide and it works fine. I always thought there was a performance hit to show/hide vs detach, but it looks like I've had it the wrong way around all this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by some parts of your code:

- What's the `entryView` function and when is it called?
- Why does the `toolBar` function exist as opposed to being inline? From where else is it called?
- Why are you creating functions like that? Creating a variable without `var` is bad practice, always makes global variables, and will be forbidden in ES5 strict mode. You should create functions like this:

  ```
  var someFunction = function(arg1, arg2) { … };
  ```

  or like this:

  ```
  function someFunction(arg1, arg2) { … }
  ```
- Why are you giving each function a second name (e.g. `_toolBar`)? The "private" name will only be in scope inside the function.

The menu doesn't have to be in global scope, just in a scope that's common to both functions.

I would refactor it like this (knowing very little about the design of your application), inlining `toolBar`:

```
function entryView() {
    var menuButton = $('<div/>' {'class': 'menuButton'}), menu = $('<div/>', {'class': 'menu'});

    $.getJSON('ajax', function(o) {
        var $enum2 = ss.IEnumerator.getEnumerator(dto.TransmittalDates);
        while ($enum2.moveNext()) {
            var dateTime = $enum2.get_current();
            $('.menu').append($('<div/>' {'class': 'menuItem'}).text(dateTime.toString()));
        }
    });

    menuButton.click(function(o) {
          menuButton.append(menu);
    });
}
```

Comment: also, won't this `$('.menu').append(...` not actually act on the `div` with the class `menu` that he created and is storing in the `var menu` ? it should be `$('.menu', menu).append(...` ...I think (again, having hardly the faintest idea what the intentions are here).